# $x^2$ is congruent to $-1 \bmod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

In general, how do you solve $x^2$ is congruent to $-1 \bmod p$, where $p$ is an odd prime and $x$ is an integer.

Specifically, I need to solve $x^2\equiv-1 \pmod{29}$

Comment: You could use $x=\frac{p-1}{2}!$ in general. Not fun to compute.

Comment: Alternatively, you can find any non-square $a$ modulo $p$ and compute $a^{(p-1)/4}$.

Comment: Since $2$ is not a square modulo $29$, you can thus compute $2^{7}\bmod 29$ to get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can figure out
$$ 29 = 25 + 4 = 5^2 + 2^2 $$
in your head, you see
$$ 5^2 + 2^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {29}, $$
$$ 5^2 \equiv - 2^2 \pmod {29}. $$
Bothe 2 and 5 are relatively prime to $29,$ either one has a multiplicative inverse mod 29.
$$ \frac{5^2}{2^2} \equiv -1 \pmod {29},  $$
$$ \left( \frac{5}{2} \right)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {29}.  $$
So, you need to figure out the multiplicative inverse of $2 \pmod {29}$ and multiply that by $5.$ whatever that becomes $\pmod {29}$ is what you need.

Not a coincidence: the other square root is
$$ - \frac{5}{2} \equiv \frac{2}{5} \pmod{29}.  $$

Comment: I think you need to explicitly state that $a^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ implies that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and that $p $ must be a sum of two squares. A comment on OP invokes but does not name Wilson's theorem which is all wrapped up in this.

Comment: weird for me , but..... it's clever and useful.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 29$ then $(-x)^2 \equiv -1 \mod 29$  So I only need to check $x = \pm 1.... \pm 14$

If $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 29$ then $x^2 = 29m - 1$. And $m \le 14 \implies 29m - 1 \le 14^2 = 28*7 \approx 29*7 -1$ so we just need to check the first $7$ multiples of $29$.

They are $28, 57, 86, 115, 144, 173, 202$.  Of those only $144 = (\pm 12)^2$ is a perfect square.

So $x = 12, 17$.

I'm not sure how to do this other than trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv b(m\acute{o}d\, p)$ iff $p|(a-b)$ thus $x^2\equiv-1(m\acute{o}d\,29)$ implies $29|x^2+1$ then exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2+1=29m$ so, $x=\pm\sqrt{29m-1}$, then you need $29m-1\geq 0$ so, $m\in \mathbb{N}$ it's sufficient.

Comment: Some solutions could be $\sqrt{28}$ if $m=1$, $\sqrt{57}$,($m=2$), etc.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that x is suppose to be an integer

Answer (score 0):

As $29$ is a small prime, you simply compute the first squares modulo $29$:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
n&\pm1&\pm 2&\pm3&\pm4&\pm 5&\dotsm \\
\hline
n^2&1&4&9&16&-4&\dotsm
\end{array}$$
Now  we have $5^2=(-1)2^2$, whence $-1=(5\cdot2^{-1})^2$. As $2^{-1}=15$, we have
$$-1=(5\cdot15)^2=(-12)^2\enspace\text{and of course}\enspace 12^2.$$