# How to solve a non-linear system of modulus equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations, polynomial-congruences

I have the following problem:

$$ 2x^2 + 8 \equiv 6 \;(\bmod\;13)$$
$$x \equiv 2 \;(\bmod\;15)$$

I have tried applying the Chinese remainder theorem, but could not figure out how to make it work, as this equation is quadratic. I have also tried saying $x = 2 + k \cdot 15$ and inserting this into the first equation, however that did not help either - why did I get the wrong result?.

Comment: Have you checked about quadratic residue? Here is a link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: $2x^2+8\equiv6\implies2x^2\equiv-2\implies x^2\equiv-1\implies x\equiv\pm5\mod 13$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How does the last step work? I can achieve it with trial and error, but not in any fast way.

Comment: @Maoepr3n:  I just figured $13(1)-1$ is not a square but $13(2)-1$ is, but cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967582/x2-is-congruent-to-1-bmod-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Solutions to the first equation are $x\equiv\pm5\mod13$.

Now can you apply the Chinese remainder theorem?